# Mongo aggregation framework, Sort and then group not working

Tags: mongodb, sorting, aggregation-framework

I am trying sort data by date first and then group on another field.
It is not working to me.

***The question I am trying to answer is: Select the most recent distinct cid?***

given this data:

```
db.summary.save({"lid" : 5, "date" : 5, "cid" : 2, "circles" : [ 2 ] })
db.summary.save({"lid" : 2, "date" : 2, "cid" : 1, "circles" : [ 2 ] })
db.summary.save({"lid" : 4, "date" : 0, "cid" : 3, "circles" : [ 2 ] })
db.summary.save({"lid" : 3, "date" : 3, "cid" : 2, "circles" : [ 2 ] })
db.summary.save({"lid" : 1, "date" : 1, "cid" : 1, "circles" : [ 2 ] })

db.summary.aggregate( {$match :{circles: 2}, $sort: {date: -1}, $group: {_id: '$cid'}} )
```

I am doing a match first on circles,
then a sort on date,
then a group on cid

The result I am getting:

```
{
    "result" : [
        {
            "_id" : 3
        },
        {
            "_id" : 1
        },
        {
            "_id" : 2
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1
}
```

**Here is my analysis:**

before matching or sorting by date, the data was:

```
"lid" : 5, "date" : 5, "cid" : 2
"lid" : 2, "date" : 2, "cid" : 1
"lid" : 4, "date" : 0, "cid" : 3
"lid" : 3, "date" : 3, "cid" : 2
"lid" : 1, "date" : 1, "cid" : 1
```

After sorting by date, the data set would be:

```
"lid" : 5, "date" : 5, "cid" : 2
"lid" : 3, "date" : 3, "cid" : 2
"lid" : 2, "date" : 2, "cid" : 1 
"lid" : 1, "date" : 1, "cid" : 1
"lid" : 4, "date" : 0, "cid" : 3
```

So after grouping, the result I expect is:

```
{
    "result" : [
        {
            "_id" : 2
        },
        {
            "_id" : 1
        },
        {
            "_id" : 3
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1
}
```

What query does solve my problem?

Why is the current query not working for me?

Comment: Your pipeline parameters to `aggregate` need to either be put in an array or passed as independent objects instead of one big object.  And your question talks about grouping on `cid` but the command is grouping on `$date`.

Comment: That was a typo. It should be $group: {_id: '$cid'}

Answer (score 39, accepted):

When you `$group` after a `$sort` in the pipeline, the previous sort is lost.  You'd have to do something like this instead so that the date you want to sort by is available after the grouping:

```js
db.summary.aggregate(
    {$match: {circles: 2}},
    {$group: {_id: '$cid', date: {$max: '$date'}}},
    {$sort: {date: -1}});
```

result:

```js
[ { _id: 2, date: 5 }, 
  { _id: 1, date: 2 }, 
  { _id: 3, date: 0 } ]
```

Add a `$project` to the end of the pipeline if you want to reshape the output.

Comment: Thanks! That is exactly what I was looking for even though I have already figured it out by the time you answered :)

Comment: don't forget that if you want to sort anything on the $group you must include it in the $sort with '_id.date'.
check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21265170/mongodb-aggregation-sort-not-working

Comment: "When you $group after a $sort in the pipeline, the previous sort is lost. " this is not really true (possibly outdated). Not only is it possible, but it is the preferred way since this way sort can use indexes: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sort/#sort-operator-and-performance

Comment: @slouc What I meant is that while the input of the $group receives its docs in $sort order, the output order of the $group doesn't maintain that order based on which group doc was created first (which is what the OP was expecting).

Comment: @JohnnyHK Yeah, perhaps there was a misunderstanding. Sort before group will result in sorted items within each group, but groups themselves may be in any order. I was dealing with this today and your statement made me think that $sort before $group will not really achieve anything, which is not true (since it does affect the items ordering within the group).