# MongoDB query with sort on multiple keys

Tags: mongodb, sorting, mongodb-query

I've got a MongoDB setup and running and I'm issuing a query that looks like this:

```
db.indexCollection.aggregate([
  {$match:
    {'term': {$regex: 'gas'},
     'term': {$regex: 'carbon'},
     'term': {$regex: 'hydro'}}
  },
  {$sort:
      {'documentFrequency': 1,
       'postingsList._id.termFrequency': 1}
    },
  {$group:
     {_id: {_id: '$postingsList._id.documentID'}}
  }
],
{allowDiskUse: true});
```

The documentIDs that are returned should contain all of the three words (or subwords) specified in the match expression (logical AND), sorted by document frequency in ascending order (priority to small document frequencies) and term frequency in descending order (priority to documents that make the most use of these terms, thus have the highest term frequency).

However, I notice that when I change the value associated with 'postingsList._id.termFrequency' from 1 to -1, nothing changes.. which makes me think that I'm doing something wrong with the sorting. The order of the output (just a list of documentIDs) does change if I change the value associated with the 'documentFrequency'. 
Any ideas?

EDIT:

Sample output format when I execute a simple find query on the key 'term',

```
{
    “_id” : ObjectId(“5941b6ad3de5cb1799f8ea26"),
    “term” : “gases”,
    “documentFrequency” : 2,
    “postingsList” : [
        {
            “documentID” : 8317982,
            “termFrequency” : 4
        },
        {
            “documentID” : 9587169,
            “termFrequency” : 1
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Can you show the sample documents?

Comment: Look at the edit

Comment: That's not a valid document. Is `postingsList` actually an array? Such as `"postingsList": [ { "_id": { ... }, { "_id": { ... } } ]` Or are the `"_id"` fields here **really** named keys `"postingsList": { "123": { ... }, "456": { ... } }`? Because that's the only way the document would be valid. So your question remains unclear, since what you are telling us you have for a document is not actually possible.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, I have fixed it

Answer (score 0):

The output after the $group stage is not as you were hoping, because a [$group stage's output may not reflect the order of the input data](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14514569/174843); to be specific, the documentation says:

> [$group does not order its output documents.](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/)

If you want the output to be ordered after you do a $group, then you need to put a $sort after the $group.

Comment: This really should be a comment and not an answer. Largely because it simply does not address the actual question asked.