# Mongo DB query for combining sorting and grouping

Tags: database, mongodb, mongodb-query, nosql, aggregate

Let's say I have a collection with the following (dummy) data:

| Country | State | Population Density (people per km^2) | Cases (in millions) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| USA | New York | 161 | 1.03 |
| USA | California | 95 | 4.47 |
| Germany | Berlin | 4,227 | 0.19 |
| India | Kerala | 859 | 4.09 |
| India | Karnataka | 319 | 2.95 |
| India | Maharashtra | 370 | 6.47 |

What is an optimized mongodb query to get results grouped by country and sorted by the count of states, also each group should contain states sorted by 'Cases'?

The results should look like this in JSON

```
{
  'results': [
      {
         'country'   : 'India',
         'num_states': 3,
         'states': [
              {
                 'State': 'Maharashtra',
                 'Cases': 6.47,
                 'PPD'  : 370,
              },
              {
                 'State': 'Kerala',
                 'Cases': 4.09,
                 'PPD'  : 859,
              },
              {
                 'State': 'Karnataka',
                 'Cases': 2.95,
                 'PPD'  : 319,
              }
          ]
      },
      {
         'country'   : 'USA',
         'num_states': 2,
         'states': [
              {
                 'State': 'California',
                 'Cases': 4.47,
                 'PPD'  : 95,
              },
              {
                 'State': 'New York',
                 'Cases': 1.03,
                 'PPD'  : 161,
              }
          ]
      },
      {
         'country'   : 'Germany',
         'num_states': 1,
         'states': [
              {
                 'State': 'Berlin',
                 'Cases': 0.19,
                 'PPD'  : 4227,
              }
          ]
      },
  ]
}
```

Note: My actual data is different, but the use case is the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first `sort` by cases `-1`
then `group` by country
add new field for sorting
and project

```
db.collection.aggregate(
[
  {
    '$sort': {
      'Cases': -1
    }
  }, {
    '$group': {
      '_id': {
        'country': '$country'
      }, 
      'num_states': {
        '$sum': 1
      }, 
      'states': {
        '$push': {
          'states': '$$ROOT.state', 
          'cases': '$$ROOT.Cases', 
          'ppd': '$$ROOT.Density'
        }
      }
    }
  }, {
    '$addFields': {
      'sorf': {
        '$max': '$states.cases'
      }
    }
  }, {
    '$sort': {
      'sorf': -1
    }
  }, {
    '$project': {
      'country': '$_id.country', 
      'num_states': '$num_states', 
      'states': 1, 
      '_id': 0
    }
  }
])
```

Comment: If we group after sorting, then the initial sort order is lost: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14513185/mongo-aggregation-framework-sort-and-then-group-not-working

Comment: so the initial sorting works for in array and for global sorting, I use `$addFields` and then sort the whole docs with `sorf` field

Comment: just tested it on mongo-playground, initial sort does not work

Comment: and the about last sort ?

Comment: the last sort is sorting the countries, but not the states inside them

Answer (score 0):

- `$sort` - sort by cases in descending order
- `$group` - group by country and construct an array of states, and get total count of states
- `$sort` - sort by number of states in descending order
- `$project` - rename the required fields

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$sort": {
      "cases": -1
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$country",
      num_states: {
        $sum: 1
      },
      states: {
        $push: {
          state: "$state",
          cases: "$cases",
          PPD: "$population"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$sort": {
      "num_states": -1
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      country: "$_id",
      num_states: 1,
      states: 1,
      _id: 0
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playgroud](https://mongoplayground.net/p/RwS_qFT7PHB)