# Mongoose sort document by which document has a more recent parent/related document

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I have `Shop` documents which each have `Order` documents.

```js
const orderSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  shop: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, required: true, ref: 'Shop' },
  item: { type: String },
  paidOn: { type: Date },
});

const Order = mongoose.model('Order', orderSchema);

// Shop Schema
const shopSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: { type: String },
});

const Shop = mongoose.model('Shop', shopSchema);
```

I want to list shops by which shop had the most recent orders.

I tried to `$sort` orders by `paidOn` and `$group` the order's shops.

```js
  const aggregatedShops = await Order.aggregate([
    {
      $lookup: {
        from: Shop.collection.collectionName,
        let: { shop: '$shop' },
        pipeline: [{ $match: { $expr: { $eq: ['$_id', '$$shop'] } } }],
        as: 'shop',
      },
    },
    { $unwind: '$shop' },
    { $group: { _id: '$shop' } },

    { $sort: { paidOn: -1 } },
    {
      $facet: {
        metadata: [{ $count: 'total' }, { $addFields: { page: +page } }],
        data: [{ $skip: (+page - 1) * limit }, { $limit: +limit }],
      },
    },
  ]).exec();
```

But the order of the aggregated shops doesn't come out as expected.

The actual order changes every time I rerun the program. But here's an example:

```
Actual order or shops: 

    Shop Name         Dates of orders. Orders listed by most recent
[
  { 'Pizza town': '9/29/2022, 9/20/2022' },
  { 'Goddess Body Shop': '9/24/2022, 9/21/2022' },
  { 'Kitchen Store': '9/30/2022, 9/19/2022' },
  { 'Book Store': '9/23/2022, 9/22/2022' }
]


Order of shops should be: 

    Shop Name         Dates of orders. Orders listed by most recent
[
  { 'Kitchen Store': '9/30/2022, 9/19/2022' },
  { 'Pizza town': '9/29/2022, 9/20/2022' },
  { 'Goddess Body Shop': '9/24/2022, 9/21/2022' },
  { 'Book Store': '9/23/2022, 9/22/2022' }
]
```

How to I aggregate the shops so that they are listed by which shops most recently had an order?

**Full Code** to recreate (make sure to run `mongosh`)

Watch the console for logs that show the expected result vs the actual result.

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const connect = async (dsn) =>
  mongoose.connect(dsn, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
  });

// Order Schema

const orderSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  shop: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, required: true, ref: 'Shop' },
  item: { type: String },
  paidOn: { type: Date },
});

const Order = mongoose.model('Order', orderSchema);

// Shop Schema
const shopSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: { type: String },
});

const Shop = mongoose.model('Shop', shopSchema);

// Seeder
const seedLocalDatabase = async () => {
  await connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/newtestdb');

  await Shop.deleteMany({});

  const shopInfo = [
    {
      name: 'Goddess Body Shop',
    },
    {
      name: 'Book Store',
    },
    {
      name: 'Pizza town',
    },
    {
      name: 'Kitchen Store',
    },
  ];

  const shopInfosInsertedRes = await Shop.insertMany(shopInfo);

  await Order.deleteMany({});
  const orders = [
    {
      shop: shopInfosInsertedRes.find((shop) => shop.name === 'Goddess Body Shop')._id,
      paidOn: new Date('9/24/2022, 11:00:00 AM'),
      item: 'Coconut lip balm',
    },

    {
      shop: shopInfosInsertedRes.find((shop) => shop.name === 'Book Store')._id,
      paidOn: new Date('9/23/2022, 11:00:00 AM'),
      item: 'Little Women',
    },
    {
      shop: shopInfosInsertedRes.find((shop) => shop.name === 'Goddess Body Shop')._id,
      item: 'Mango Body Butter',
      paidOn: new Date('9/21/2022, 9:28:20 PM'),
    },
    {
      shop: shopInfosInsertedRes.find((shop) => shop.name === 'Book Store')._id,
      item: 'Green Eggs and Ham',
      paidOn: new Date('9/22/2022, 2:00:00 PM'),
    },

    {
      shop: shopInfosInsertedRes.find((shop) => shop.name === 'Pizza town')._id,
      paidOn: new Date('9/20/2022, 11:00:00 AM'),
      item: 'Pizza slice',
    },
    {
      shop: shopInfosInsertedRes.find((shop) => shop.name === 'Pizza town')._id,
      paidOn: new Date('9/29/2022, 11:00:00 AM'),
      item: 'Large Pizza',
    },

    {
      shop: shopInfosInsertedRes.find((shop) => shop.name === 'Kitchen Store')._id,
      item: 'Funnel',
      paidOn: new Date('9/19/2022, 9:28:20 PM'),
    },
    {
      shop: shopInfosInsertedRes.find((shop) => shop.name === 'Kitchen Store')._id,
      item: 'salad bowl',
      paidOn: new Date('9/30/2022, 9:28:20 PM'),
    },
  ];

  await Order.insertMany(orders);
};

// Aggregation
(async () => {
  await seedLocalDatabase();

  const page = 1;
  const limit = 15;
  const aggregatedShops = await Order.aggregate([
    {
      $lookup: {
        from: Shop.collection.collectionName,
        let: { shop: '$shop' },
        pipeline: [{ $match: { $expr: { $eq: ['$_id', '$$shop'] } } }],
        as: 'shop',
      },
    },
    { $unwind: '$shop' },
    { $group: { _id: '$shop' } },

    { $sort: { paidOn: -1 } },
    {
      $facet: {
        metadata: [{ $count: 'total' }, { $addFields: { page: +page } }],
        data: [{ $skip: (+page - 1) * limit }, { $limit: +limit }],
      },
    },
  ]).exec();
  const orders = await Order.find({}).sort({ paidOn: -1 });

  aggregatedShops[0].data.map((ord) => ({
    [ord._id.name]: orders
      .filter((o) => o.shop.toJSON() === ord._id._id.toJSON())
      .sort((a, b) => a - b)
      .map((or) => `${or.paidOn.getMonth() + 1}/${or.paidOn.getDate()}/${or.paidOn.getFullYear()}`)
      // [0],
      .join(', '),
  }));

  // below are just logs in order to display the result result
  console.log('');
  console.log('');
  console.log('Order of aggregated shops: ');
  console.log('');
  console.log('Actual order: ');
  console.log('');
  console.log(aggregatedShops[0].data.map((ord) => ord._id.name));
  console.log('');
  console.log('');
  console.log('Order should be: ');
  console.log('');
  console.log(
    aggregatedShops[0].data
      .map((ord) => [
        ord._id.name,
        orders
          .filter((o) => o.shop.toJSON() === ord._id._id.toJSON())
          .sort((a, b) => b.paidOn - a.painOn)
          .map((o) => o.paidOn)[0],
      ])
      .sort((a, b) => b[1] - a[1])
      .map((p) => p[0])
  );
  console.log('');
  console.log('');
  console.log('Actual: ');

  console.log('');
  console.log('    Shop Name         Dates of orders. Orders listed by most recent');
  console.log(
    aggregatedShops[0].data.map((ord) => ({
      [ord._id.name]: orders
        .filter((o) => o.shop.toJSON() === ord._id._id.toJSON())
        .map((or) => or.paidOn)
        .sort((a, b) => b - a)
        .map((paidOn) => `${paidOn.getMonth() + 1}/${paidOn.getDate()}/${paidOn.getFullYear()}`)
        .join(', '),
    }))
  );
  console.log('');
  console.log('');

  console.log('Should be: ');

  console.log('');
  console.log('    Shop Name         Dates of orders. Orders listed by most recent');
  console.log(
    aggregatedShops[0].data
      .map((shop) => ({
        [shop._id.name]: orders
          .filter((o) => o.shop.toJSON() === shop._id._id.toJSON())
          .map((or) => or.paidOn)
          .sort((a, b) => b - a)
          .map((paidOn) => paidOn),
      }))
      .sort((a, b) => Object.values(b)[0][0] - Object.values(a)[0][0])
      .map((shop) => ({
        [Object.keys(shop)[0]]: Object.values(shop)[0]
          .map((paidOn) => `${paidOn.getMonth() + 1}/${paidOn.getDate()}/${paidOn.getFullYear()}`)
          .join(', '),
      }))
  );
  console.log('');
  mongoose.disconnect();
})();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found the answer here

> When you $group after a $sort in the pipeline, the previous sort is
> lost.

[Mongo aggregation framework, Sort and then group not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14513185/mongo-aggregation-framework-sort-and-then-group-not-working)

this fixed my issue

```js
   { $group: { _id: '$shop', date: { $max: '$paidOn' } } },
   { $sort: { date: -1 } },
```

full aggregation

```js
  const aggregatedShops = await Order.aggregate([
    {
      $lookup: {
        from: Shop.collection.collectionName,
        let: { shop: '$shop' },
        pipeline: [{ $match: { $expr: { $eq: ['$_id', '$$shop'] } } }],
        as: 'shop',
      },
    },
    { $unwind: '$shop' },
    // { $group: { _id: '$shop' } },
    { $group: { _id: '$shop', date: { $max: '$paidOn' } } },

    { $sort: { date: -1 } },
    {
      $facet: {
        metadata: [{ $count: 'total' }, { $addFields: { page: +page } }],
        data: [{ $skip: (+page - 1) * limit }, { $limit: +limit }],
      },
    },
  ]).exec();
```